# Xcode - Modify Library Search Path Based on device which code is being compiled for

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode4

I am sure this has been asked before, however I have been banging my head against a brick wall all afternoon trying to figure out how to achieve this using XCode 4.

I have a lib which was distributed by a 3rd party. They actually ship 2 different versions, one for use in the simulator, and one for use with the actual device.

I would like to know, what is the recommended way for handling situations like this in XCode 4; in XCode 3, I could simply have specified a new target. I wish to avoid creating a fat binary via lipo containing both libs, but if that is the only feasible option available to me, then so be it.

Ideally what I would like to do is modify the Library Search path based upon the current device the project is being compiled for such as:

Simulator: /path/to/simulator/lib.a

Device /path/to/device/lib.a

If I could automate the process so once I had set it up, it was transparent, all the better.

Many thanks for taking the time to read this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still create new targets in XCode4 - just go to your project in the navigator sidebar, select it and in the project editor you can select "new target".

However I would actually recommend you use lipo to create a fat binary.  I believe the simulator part gets stripped out as part of the build phase so it should not impact executable size.

Answer (score 8):

XCode define `$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME)` to be 'iphoneos' or 'iphonesimulator' base on the target "device".  As long as your library path includes one of those strings, you can set 
`LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS` in your targets or project to something like:

```
/path/to/$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME)/lib.a
```

Hint: you can see this in action by clicking "All" in Building Settings, and then selecting *Editor > Show Setting Names* and *Editor > Show Setting Definitions* in the menus.  To see if the final value is what you expect, switch back to values using *Editor > Show Setting Values*.

Comment: $(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME) ftw

Comment: This fails. $(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME) returns iphoneos even when simulator is selected as the build target. Maybe it's a bug in XCode 7.1??

Comment: I agree @CommaToast this appears to now be a bug.  Tested w/ XCode Version 7.2 (7C68)

Comment: I have the same problem here. Did you find a solution? I'm using a workaround. I'm building the project from makefiles and I'm overriding the value of EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME to "-iphonesimulator".
Sample: $(XBUILD) -workspace "" -scheme "" -sdk iphonesimulator -arch x86_64 -configuration Release EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME="-iphonesimulator" -derivedDataPath build clean build